# no such a table

Tags: android, sqlite

I am trying make a basic database with the SQLliteDatabase but It is keep giving me this error. I have been **stuck for a very long time**, i guess the mistake i make is very simple but I can not find it. **If someone could help it would be GREAT**

```
01-06 15:07:47.885: I/Database(1824): sqlite returned: error code = 1, msg = no such table: webpages
01-06 15:07:47.904: E/Database(1824): Error inserting id=1 phone=10001 name=Ivan
01-06 15:07:47.904: E/Database(1824): android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: no such table: webpages: , while compiling: INSERT INTO webpages(id, phone, name) VALUES(?, ?, ?);
```

Here is the code I use

```
public class DatabaseHandler extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
    /**
     * The name of the database
     */
    private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "Weboff.db";

    /**
     * The name of the (only) table.
     */
    private static final String TABLE_NAME = "webpages";

    /**
     * The name of the first column (ID)
     */
    private static final String COL_ID = "id";

    /**
     * The name of the second column (NAME)
     */
    private static final String COL_NAME = "name";

    /**
     * The name of the third column (PHONENUMBER)
     */
    private static final String COL_PHONE = "phone";

    /**
     * A constructor which builds a DatabaseHandler object. Note that calling
     * the constructor does not create a database. This does not happen until
     * the first call to getReadableDatabase() or getWriteableDatabase()
     * 
     * @param context
     *            In this case, a reference to LecturerActivity
     */
    public DatabaseHandler(Context context) {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, 1);
    }

    /**
     * This method is called when the database is created for the first time.
     * This is where the creation of tables and the initial population of the
     * tables should happen.
     */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        String CREATE_CONTACTS_TABLE = "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_NAME + "("
                + COL_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY," + COL_NAME + " TEXT,"
                + COL_PHONE + " TEXT" + ")";
        db.execSQL(CREATE_CONTACTS_TABLE);
    }

    /**
     * Called when the database needs to be upgraded. Only relevant when you
     * have multiple versions of the database scheme in play.
     * 
     */
    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldNum, int newNum) {
        // Drop older table if exist and create fresh
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_NAME);
        onCreate(db);
    }

    /**
     * Use this method to add a Lecturer to the database.
     * 
     * @param lecturer
     *            the Lecturer you want to add
     */
    public void addLecturer(Lecturer lecturer) {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
        values.put(COL_ID, lecturer.getID());
        values.put(COL_NAME, lecturer.getName());
        values.put(COL_PHONE, lecturer.getPhoneNumber());
        db.insert(TABLE_NAME, null, values);
        db.close();
    }

    /**
     * Use this method to get all of the Lecturers in the database.
     * 
     * @return a list of Lecturer objects, one per row
     */
    public List<Lecturer> getAll() {
        List<Lecturer> list = new ArrayList<Lecturer>();
        String selectQuery = "SELECT  * FROM " + TABLE_NAME;
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
        Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);
        if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
            do {
                Lecturer lecturer = new Lecturer(cursor.getInt(0),
                        cursor.getString(1), cursor.getString(2));
                list.add(lecturer);
            } while (cursor.moveToNext());
        }
        return list;
    }

    /**
     * Use this method to remove all of the Lecturers from the database. This is
     * useful when experimenting. After dropping all tables, the initial state
     * of the database is re-created.
     */
    public void removeAll() {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_NAME);
        onCreate(db);
    }

    /**
     * This method removes one lecturer from the database.
     * 
     * @param lecturer
     *            the Lecturer to remove
     */
    public void deleteLecturer(Lecturer lecturer) {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        db.delete(TABLE_NAME, COL_ID + " = ?",
                new String[] { String.valueOf(lecturer.getID()) });
        db.close();
    }

    /**
     * This method updates the data stored in the database for one Lecturer.
     * 
     * @param lecturer
     *            the Lecturer to update
     * @return the number of rows affected
     */
    public int updateLecturer(Lecturer lecturer) {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
        values.put(COL_NAME, lecturer.getName());
        values.put(COL_PHONE, lecturer.getPhoneNumber());
        return db.update(TABLE_NAME, values, COL_ID + " = ?",
                new String[] { String.valueOf(lecturer.getID()) });
    }

    /**
     * This method gets a single Lecturer from the database, using the ID field
     * as a key
     * ;
     * @param id
     *            the ID of the Lecturer we want
     * @return a Lecturer object
     */
    public Lecturer getLecturer(int id) {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
        Cursor cursor = db.query(TABLE_NAME, new String[] { COL_ID, COL_NAME,
                COL_PHONE }, COL_ID + "=?",
                new String[] { String.valueOf(id) }, null, null, null, null);
        if (cursor != null) {
            cursor.moveToFirst();
        }
        Lecturer lecturer = new Lecturer(Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(0)),
                cursor.getString(1), cursor.getString(2));
        return lecturer;
    }
}



public class Lecturer {

    /**
     * The ID assigned to the lecturer. Starts at 1.
     */
    private int ID;

    /**
     * The full name of the lecturer.
     */
    private String name;

    /**
     * The internal phone number of the lecturer. 4 digits.
     */
    private String phoneNumber;


    /** Builds a new Lecturer object
     * 
     * @param ID The ID assigned to the lecturer.
     * @param name The full name of the lecturer
     * @param phoneNumber The internal phone number of the lecturer
     */
    public Lecturer(int ID, String name, String phoneNumber){
        this.ID = ID;
        this.name = name;
        this.phoneNumber = phoneNumber;
    }

    /**
     * Get the full name of the lecturer
     * 
     * @return the lecturers full name
     */
    public String getName(){
        return this.name;
    }

    /**
     * Set the name of the lecturer
     * 
     * @param name the lecturers full name
     */
    public void setName(String name){
        this.name = name;
    }

    /**
     * Get the phone number of the lecturer
     * 
     * @return the lecturers full name
     */
    public String getPhoneNumber(){
        return this.phoneNumber;
    }

    /**
     * Set the phone number of the lecturer
     * 
     * @param name the lecturers phone number
     */
    public void setPhoneNumber(String phoneNumber){
        this.phoneNumber = phoneNumber;
    }

    /**
     * Get the ID of the lecturer
     * 
     * @return the lecturers ID
     */
    public int getID() {
        return ID;
    }

    /**
     * Set the ID of the lecturer
     * 
     * @param name the lecturers ID
     */
    public void setID(int iD) {
        ID = iD;
    }
}




And in the onCreate method 

public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.home);


        regularExpresionStrings();


        dh = new DatabaseHandler(this);
        dh.addLecturer(new Lecturer(1, "Ivan", "10001"));

          Log.d("Database: ", "Listing all lecturers..");
          List<Lecturer> list = dh.getAll();  
          for (Lecturer lr : list) {
                String log = "ID:" + lr.getID() +" Name: " + lr.getName() + " Phone: " + lr.getPhoneNumber();
                Log.d("Database: ", log); 
            }
```

Comment: Just a suggestion. Have you changed the code since you originally created the database file? Perhaps the code is now correct, but you're still working with a database that was created without that table. Get rid of the file and try it from scratch.

Comment: try after changing `")"` to `");"` in CREATE_CONTACTS_TABLE String because table is not created

Comment: Also, try retrieving the db file and opening it with a SQLite viewer program and find out what tables are actually inside it.

Comment: put `log.d` in onCreate to check what actually string is setted in CREATE_CONTACTS_TABLE, try do the same thing in other cases with your table name

Comment: Did you change the db and then run it on a device where the application was already installed?

Comment: It seems that in the addLecturer method the Table name is what expected webpages but in the onCreate method is not printing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use `Cursor`, your table must has `column = "_id"`, not `"id"`

Answer (score 2):

to elaborate, cursor needs an _id, you may not need to change "id" to "_id", just use to query the id as _id..

String[] columns = new String[] {"id AS _id"};

that would make the query find "id" as "_id"